Show how this sum of two fractions can be simplified into the given answer
$$\frac{k+1}{k+3} - (\frac{k+1}{k+2})^2 = \frac{(k+1)}{(k+3)(k+2)^2}$$
Supposedly, the common denominator is $(k+3)(k+2)$ and not $(k+3)(k+2)^2$ and I don't understand why. Would anyone be willing to work this problem through all the way, or explain why the common denominator is $(k+3)(k+2)$ and not $(k+3)(k+2)^2$?
Edit: Added in photos of the answer key per request


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The common denominator is $(k+3)(k+2)^2$ as you say.

It's likely a typo on someone's part. Can you show what you expect the RHS to be?

I've added pictures of what the PDF shows me
After I tried working the problem myself I end up with an extra factor of (k+1) and a coefficient of 2. Gonna redo.

$$\frac{k+1}{k+3} - (\frac{k+1}{k+2})^2=(k+1)\bigg[\frac{1}{k+3}-\frac{k+1}{(k+2)^2}\bigg]\\=(k+1)\bigg[\frac{(k+2)^2-(k+1)(k+3)}{k+3(k+2)^2}\bigg]\\=(k+1)\bigg[\frac{k^2+4k+4-(k^2-4k-3)}{(k+3)(k+2)^2}\bigg]\\=(k+1)\bigg[\frac{1}{(k+3)(k+2)^2}\bigg]\\=\frac{(k+1)}{(k+3)(k+2)^2}$$
I don't understand what's wrong

Nothing's wrong, this is the answer. Thank you!
